# Outlook (Office 365) is stripping HTML element class and ID attribute when forwarding or replying to email

Tags: outlook, office365

I have created a HTML template mail through PowerShell script and send it to recipient clients. When client replies or forward the custom HTML email template, all HTML elements class and ID attribute is removed automatically when using Outlook Office 365 desktop Client.

However, when I try it in Outlook Web App in browser everything works out smoothly. Can someone please help me?

Below is the sample HTML which is generated through code:

```
<center>
<table width="900px" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" style="border:1px solid #f0f0f0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img width="200" height="100" src="https://www.sessionm.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/*****.png"></td>
<td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px">*********** <br>
<span style="font-size:16px;color:blue">Update Tech Panel Data</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><br>
Hi <strong>*****</strong>, <br>
<br>
Thank you for nominating yourself to be part of the interview process held on <strong>
07/24/2021 18:30:00</strong>. Your general detail inside the system is shown below the table.
<br>
<br>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:800px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold">
PSID</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold">
Name</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold">
Client</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold">
Email ID</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold">
Client Email ID</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;border:1px solid #000;">****</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;border:1px solid #000;">****</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;border:1px solid #000;">****</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;border:1px solid #000;">*****</td>
<td style="padding:5px 1px;border:1px solid #000;">****</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
Request you to please provide your input details in below table by replying to this email chain. Also, please
<strong>attach necessary documents</strong> which are related to the interview process.
<br>
<br>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:800px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:5px 1px; background-color:#f0f0f0; border:1px solid #000; font-weight:bold; width:400px">
Interview Taken in Jul Month</td>
<td title="titlelayout_getInterviewCountForMonth" class="classlayout_getInterviewCountForMonth" style="padding:4px 1px; border:1px solid #000; font-family:'stylelayout_getInterviewCountForMonth'">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Thanks And Regards,<br>
<strong>****</strong>
<table style="color:#fff; display:none;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0;opacity:0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td title="titlelayout_spID" class="classlayout_spID">***`enter code here`</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word (or rather Word-light compiled into a dll) to display and edit HTML messages, so your HTML would be converted into DOCX (or something internal), then back to HTML again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I just want to retain my ID and Class HTML elements attribute and I tried lot of ways but nothing yet successful. How can we preserve this?

Comment: I don't think you can in the Windows version of Outlook.